# jQuery datepicker doens't change ng-empty if I select a date

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker, razorengine

I have a view in which I have a input field with jquery ui date picker.
I want to disable button if the field is empty.

**HTML(cshtml-ASP.Net):**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From, new { ng_model = "From", id = "dFrom", @class = "form-control datepick", placeholder = "Select From date", tabindex = "2" })

 <input ng-disabled="!From" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('.datepick').each(function () {
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd MM, y', maxDate: new Date() });
            });
        });
    })
```

But if I select a date, the field doesn't change anything (like: `ng-empty` to ng-not empty) and the button still disabled.
How can I solve the issue?

Comment: I found the solution! Just placed my jquery-ui before angular.js.

Comment: I found the solution! Just placed my jquery-ui before angular.
Before that my angularjs was 3rd position`code <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-disabled` makes the angular add the html `disabled='disabled'` whenever you type something into the selected field (any character other than space). That also works with a jQuery `datepicker` field.

ASP runs on server side. It only generates the code that you run on the client/browser side.

See if the following test works for you. It disables the first input field and the second button whenever something is entered into the third datepicker field (it also reverses the effect when the field becomes blank).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
  <div ng-app="">
     <input ng-disabled='!mydate' type="text"/><br/><br/><br/>
     <input ng-disabled='!mydate' type="button" value="Add"/><br/><br/> 
     <br/><br/><br/><br/>
     Date:
     <input type="text" id="datepicker" ng-model='mydate'>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting there?

Comment: i want if i select a date from datepicker, error message should be gone. You can visit my link and login. Click add new employee then you will understand. Error message won't be gone even you select a date from input field. I used ng-show='!inputfield && $touched' for the input field and for the button ng-disabled='!inputfield'

Answer (score 0):

I tested your site. When you empty-out the `JoiningDate` field completely, then single-click inside the field, use the popped up datepick-calendar to select a date, the selected date gets populated into the `JoiningDate` field (appears visually on the screen, in the space provided for the field). But, it doesn't get populated into the angular's model (which has name as JoiningDateAdd. That remains as `undefined`).

You can debug this behaviour by using `Firebug for Firefox` combined with `Angular Scope for Firefox` (Right click the `JoiningDate`, inspect it in Firebug, right-click the field inside Firebug and Inspect it in Angular Scope. The field there (named JoiningDateAdd remains `undefined`).

This behaviour has been discussed extensively at SO and a lot of fixes have been proposed (Some of them may be relevant, some not, based on the versions of jquery, bootstrap, angular used). Just search in google for -

```
jquery datepicker not updating angular model
bootstrap datepicker not updating angular model
```

Anyway, I pulled relevant code from your site (including css/js files), and created a small test case. It gave me "datepicker() not a function". When I used a later version of jquery-ui.js file, it worked out `OK`. So, in effect, I couldn't reproduce it. I guess it takes few more combinations of switches for the problem to manifest. You could use the test sample below and see if you could reproduce the problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- This gives "datepicker()" not known error -->
  <!--<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min"></script>-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

  <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css"></style>

  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="Scripts/bootstrap.css"></style>   
  <link href="Scripts/bootstrap-theme.css"></style>     

  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>    

  <script>      
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').each(function () {
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd MM, y', maxDate: new Date() });
            });
        });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
  <div ng-app="">
     NationalID: <input type="text" id="NationalID" ng-model='NationalIDAdd'>
     <span ng-show="!NationalIDAdd">Please Fill the field!</span><br>
     DOB: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dob" ng-model='DobAdd'>
     <span ng-show="!DobAdd">Please Fill the field!</span><br><br><br><br><br>       
     <button ng-disabled="!NationalIDAdd||!DobAdd">Apply</button>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same issue associated with datetimepicker, I used controller for binding datetimepicker to the element. The issue has been fixed as follows.

```
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
       format: 'LT'
});   
$("#timepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $scope.time=e.date.format('h:mm');
});
```

Comment: try using Re arrange yourr jquery files and test. something like  `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> `